# Kohana 3.0 installation problems - New controller issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, controller, kohana, config

I've been trying to install Kohana on my own WAMP server but have been running into a bit of a dead end. I've followed the instructions [here](http://www.dealtaker.com/blog/2009/11/20/kohana-php-3-0-ko3-tutorial-part-1/) up until the .htaccess file modification;
I redirect as specified but then get an 'internal sever error' stating that it is a configuration error. I've tried a bunch of combinations and I still get the same error.

The only working method I've found is not including the .htaccess file and simply correctly pointing the bootstrap.php to the right path.
This renders my welcome.php controller example, however, I then try and create a new controller as mentioned and enter the specific path (mysite/controller_name) but I get 404 Error.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

bootstrap.php -

```
Kohana::init(array(
'base_url'      => '/shiftrunner/kohana-shiftrunner/', 
'index_file'    => ''
));
```

.htaccess - 
    # Turn on URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine On

```
# Installation directory 
RewriteBase /shiftrunner/kohana-shiftrunner Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Comment: Please note, I've situated this install in a subdirectory e.g. root/some_project/kohana

Comment: Is Kohana running in a subfolder or in the root? Can we see your .htaccess? Can we see the part of bootstrap.php regarding your 'base_url' (the array you give to Kohana::init)?

Comment: Bootstrap.php - 
`code`Kohana::init(array(
 'base_url'   => '/shiftrunner/kohana-shiftrunner/', 
 'index_file' => ''
));`code`

Comment: .htaccess - # Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory 
RewriteBase /shiftrunner/kohana-shiftrunner Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]

Comment: Hi, as mentioned above it is in a subfolder

Comment: @user - please don't put large code chunks in the comments, instead edit your post and add them.

Comment: Your settings seem fine (I am supposing that there is a newline after ´RewriteBase /shiftrunner/kohana-shiftrunner`). What is the file name of the controller you created? Where did you put the controller? And, post also the contents of the controller.

Comment: Do you have access to Apache's logs? Maybe there you'll find the reason of "internal server error".

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteBase should be `/shiftrunner/kohana-shiftrunner/` with the following slash, exactly the same as `base_url` in your bootstrap.

`index_file` should be set to `false` if you don't want it displayed, not `''`.

If the above doesn't make it work, I'd also try replacing

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

with

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```