# Cannot access controllers in Kohana, works with index.php though

Tags: controller, kohana-3

I using an Ubuntu server and I have mod_rewrite loaded but for some reason, when I type in my URL with the controller name. It shows me this:

> Not Found:
>
> The requested URL /jn/ was not found on this server.

That is weird because I do have a controller called `jn`.

It does work if I go directly to:

```
index.php/jn
```

Also, why is it not sending me a Kohana error? If I made any mistake in the code it should of send me an Kohana error, no?

Logs:

```
[error] [client 184.162.240.112] File does not exist: /var/www/jn
[error] [client 184.162.240.112] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have anything in your webserver error logs?

Comment: [Tue Jun 14 02:43:00 2011] [error] [client 184.162.240.112] File does not exist: /var/www/jn
[Tue Jun 14 02:43:00 2011] [error] [client 184.162.240.112] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico

Comment: Sorry about that... I should of put it before.

Comment: Looks like `/jn` is attempted to be loaded as a file, rather than handed off to an application. Try going through the install directions again? (Don't forget to restart Apache.)

Comment: Your environment passed all requirements.
Remove or rename the install.php file now. That's the Kohana install page... It seems everything is well setup.

Comment: I did not install MySQL and GD library... I don't need them...

Comment: You'll need to show the .htaccess file or the rewrite configuration lines from your apache config file.

Comment: What about `/index.php` and `/index.php/jn/`?

Comment: Only works when I use index.php/jn

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kohana 3.0 installation problems - New controller issues...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594370/kohana-3-0-installation-problems-new-controller-issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ubuntu, you need to modify the default Apache configuratiopn */etc/apache2/sites-available/default* to look like this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

The changes are:

- **AllowOverride** from *None* to *all*
- added line **Allow from all**